# How to download .log files from the server and save it to local disk using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I am trying to download error log files such as IIS logs, HTTP API error logs from the server and save it to my disk. These logs contain the `.log` extension.

Have tried below code to download, it works well for text files but it didn't work for the files which are of type `.log`:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
response = urlopen('https://servername/path/errorlog.txt') #doesn't work for response = urlopen('https://servername/path/errorlog.log')
data = response.read()

# Write data to file
filename = "test.txt"
file_ = open(filename, 'w')
file_.write(data)
file_.close()
```

[image: This is one error log file]

This is the error messages i am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#26>", line 1, in <module>
    response = urlopen(url)
  File "C:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 532, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 642, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 570, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python\lib\urllib\request.py", line 650, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Do you have a solution to this problem?

Comment: "but it didn't work" - was there any error? What are the contents of `data` at that time?

Comment: It seems unlikely that IIS logs are available via http(s).  Can you reach the url "https://servername/path/errorlog.log" in your browser and see the file?

Comment: getting this error: urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found ,but actually the file is present..

Comment: yes..i can reach the path  "servername/path/filename...but if filename is a.txt (text file) it works...if file is log file it wont

Comment: Are you able to download the log using that URL in a browser?

Comment: i am running this application as some specified user..that user has permission to go to that url and fetch the specified file..i am able to download text files which are present in the same directory,but i am not able to download log file present in the same directory

Comment: If you can't download it via a browser either, then it looks like you don't have a programming problem. The web server is configured to not allow you (or likely anyone) to download those files.